# Finding a Server in the network running on a specific port

Tags: java, sockets, networking, server, client

I am acutally coding an Application that allows the users to post things.
There is just one server and multiple clients, but since it isn't sure on what ip the server will run i want the server to be automatically found, the port is fixed , it is 55001.
Going thru all IP's from 1 to 255 takes years , i have already tried that, does anyone have a clean and fast solution to this?

Comment: Finding the subnet should reduce the search

Comment: @Juned Ahsan Well, let us say i'd already know the subnet for exmaple 178. So even if i already know it , it will still take a lot of time.

Comment: Will the server and clients always be on the same subnet? If so, you can use multicast UDP to find the server. If not, DNS will be your best bet.

Comment: Yeah i guess it will be the same subnet, i am not sure tho, didn't talk to our admin yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) Use broadcast to discover the server (Only IPv4 has this)
b) Use multicast to discover the server (Same code-base for IPv4 and IPv6)
c) Register the server into a DNS entry
d) Register the server, into a central server
e) Let the user type in the server IP/hostname